# What is the syntax of a crashed service log message in /var/log/messages?

Tags: systemd, filesystems, logs, syslog, crash

A few weeks ago we had a monitoring service crash which resulted in our monitoring being down for over 12 hours. I've set up a secondary log collection service for these servers, but our previous logs rotated so I dont have a good example of a crashed service to create a log metric off of. I tried just killing the process and subprocesses, but I only ever get sigterm in the logs.

Is there a standard output to the messages logfile when a service crashes I can use to search and create a metric?

Comment: There are a million ways in which your service can fail that can't be considered ahead of time. For that reason, don't use /var/log/messages for monitoring anything important -- use actual service metrics to validate correct behaviour and forward progress.

Comment: @ChrisDown Hm, okay. I thought there may be some generic systemd message but I guess not. So just doing an actual check on the service sounds like the way to go.